# Twitter and Reverse Authentication

Tags: ios, https, twitter-oauth

I want to use Twitter to sign on in an iOS application. Once the user has authenticated with Twitter I want to pass these credentials to a server in order to match these with a user profile stored in a database.

I can comunicate with my server over https, but this still doesn't tell me that the credentials I am being passed from the app are:

1. Coming from the app - as someone else could start a secure session with my service
2. Have valid credentials - that the credentials are an actual signed in twitter account and not just some made up numbers (keys etc)

Do I need to implement reverse authentication to provide a method to do this securely? (If not what method should I use to know that the information provided is correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the methodology is once you got the token/secret from the iOS client is to call the [GET account/verify_credentials](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials), then you get the user account and you can compare twitter user id or name with the one stored on your user profiles.